# Reformatting Output Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interactive-brokers

Currently I am trying to request data from the IB API, but I have a small formatting issue.

The API gives me the following output:

```
AAPL; 20190507 16:20:00; price; price; price; price; number
```

I would like the data to return as:

```
AAPL; 20190507; 16:20:00; price; price; price; price; number
```

I am using the following code

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract


class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print("AAPL", ";", bar.date, ";", bar.open, ";", bar.high, ";", bar.low, ";", bar.close, ";", bar.volume)

def main():
    app = TestApp()

    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)

    contract = Contract ()
    contract.symbol = "AAPL"
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.primaryExchange = "NASDAQ"

    app.reqHistoricalData(0, contract, "", "1 D", "1 min", "TRADES", 0, 1, False, [])

    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

bar.date in this case gives me the date and time

```
print("AAPL", ";", bar.date, ";", bar.open, ";", bar.high, ";", bar.low, ";", bar.close, ";", bar.volume)
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'; '.join(bar.date.split(' '))
```

Or:

```
bar.date.replace(' ', '; ')
```

Both of these will replace the space in the date/time output with a semicolon and space.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, `bar.date` contains `"20190507 16:20:00"`.

So you can replace `bar.date` with `"; ".join(bar.date.split(" "))` in last `print()` you've provided.